# How can I create a header background which changes as I scroll?

Tags: css

I've been asked to create a web page which has a fixed header (just a standard header bar, about 80px high, which stays in place when the page scrolls).  At the top of the page is a hero image, and when it's visible, the header should have a gradient background, (black at the top, transparent at the bottom).

Once the user has scrolled on down past the hero image, the header background should change to black.

I've seen it done, so I know it's possible, but I'm just not sure how it works and I haven't been able to figure it out.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The HTML is:

```
<div id="body">
  <div id="header">
  ... header contents (basically a logo and some navigation) ...
  </div>
<div id="pageContent">
  <div id="heroImage">
    <img src="/path/to/image" />
  </div>
  <div id="about">
    ... About ...
  </div>
  ... more sections
</div>
```

and currently the header CSS is:

```
#header {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,255) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,255) 17%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 78%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  position: fixed;
  width: '100%';
 z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to do this kind of stuff in JavaScript, since you can't really do this with css only.

In this snippet you can see how you can change the styling of the Header after scroling. You would need to check the Position of your Hero and if the Window is scrolled past this point, you can change the styling with css-classes.

Here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991797/how-to-change-css-when-user-scrolls-past-a-certain-div), for more information.

```js
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
var placeholder = document.getElementById("navbar_placeholder");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky");
        // placeholder.classList.add("display");
        nav.classList.add("shrink");
    } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
        // placeholder.classList.remove("display");
        nav.classList.remove("shrink");
    }
}
const options = {threshold: 0.5};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
        console.log(entry)
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            entry.target.classList.add('show');
        } else {
            entry.target.classList.remove('show');
        }
    });
}, options);

const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));
```

```css
:root{
    --background-color: #001728;
    --darker-background-color: #000000;
    --accent-color: #20cc5b;
    --text-color: #FFFFFF;
    --navbar-height: 80px;
}
html{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--background-color);
}
nav{
    height: var(--navbar-height);
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 4px solid var(--accent-color);
    transition-property: height;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.navbar {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
.navbar-placeholder {
    position:relative;
    height:80px;
    transition: height 0.5s;
}
.text1{
    padding: 30px;
  color: white;
}
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
.disappear {
    opacity: 0%;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;

}
.shrink {
    height: 40px;
    transition-property: height;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.display {
    display: block;
    height: var(--navbar-height);
}
h1, p{
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
}
section {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    border: 5px solid white;
}
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.show {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WeSoDev</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="navbar_placeholder" class="navbar-placeholder">
<div id="navbar">
    <nav id="nav">
      <h2 id="header">header</h2>
    </nav>
</div>  
</div>
      <section class="hidden">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </section>
    <section class="hidden">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </section>
    <section class="hidden">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </section>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!  I'm actually using React, rather than plain HTML/CSS/JS, so I was able to just add a state variable called scroll, which I updated using `window.onscroll = function () { setScroll(window.pageYOffset); };` and then I was able to use a ternary operator to decide which style to apply to the header - very simple!  Thanks again!